# Laravel minmum characters on condition ( depends on condition )

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have a scenario that the field should have `min:5` only if another request field exists? Not `required_if`.
Like if I have a products return reasons :
if the user chooses a reason and wants to add some details to the textarea (input ) so I do not need any minimum characters, while if he chooses ( Other ) reason, I do need at least 5 chars?

Here is my validation rule :

```
'item.*.reason' => ['required_if:item.*.selected_reason,other','nullable','min:5','max:3000']
```

Comment: If a user chooses a reason (and not Other) could they e.g. put 3 characters in the text area?

Comment: If they choose (other) so I need min 5 chars, otherwise, no need for that condition at all.

Comment: I'm just wondering if `required_if:reason,other|min:5` is enough e.g. if the reason is other then the field is required and has a min length of 5, otherwise it's not required but still has a min length of 5 if provided

Comment: I have edited the question , i already did this but not fully saturate my needs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that with custom validation

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'reason' => ['required'], // may be enum
    'remarks' => [
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use($request) {
            if ($request->reason === "other" && strlen($value) < 5) {
                $fail('Please provide a detailed reason.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```